# How to install @ng-select while updaing to Angular 10?

Tags: angular

Package "@ng-select/ng-select" has an incompatible.  this is the error i got while updating from angular 8 to angular 10.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G84Oa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Changelog](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2019-07-08) of `ng-select` the package does not support any Angular version which is higher than version `8`, so there is no way to use the library in the version `10`. You have to wait for updates from `ng-select` or you need to swap it to another library.

Answer (score 1):

I could see that [ng-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) v4.x currently supports till v9

You'll need to wait for the ng-select to release a compatible version for v10 or try out different library.

Please be noted that it is **not recommend to move across multiple major versions** as per [Update Guide from v8 to v10](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:10.0) by Angular Team.